# solve following integral

Tags: calculus, integration

let us consider following  integral

$$\int\frac{1}{x^3}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2} }dx$$

i have tried to separate variables  and write

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}=1-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

and then i have  introduced another variable  $y$,which is equal  $y=\frac1x$

so finally i will have  $y^3\sqrt{1-y^2}$

but how can i continue from this?should i  introduce some another  variable ,insert  $y^3$   into square root  or?please help me to continue from this,i forget calculus 2,so please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{x^3}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}}\,{\rm d}x$$

$$\int\frac{1}{x^3}\sqrt{1 - \frac1{x^2}}\,{\rm d}x$$

Substituting, $t=1-\frac{1}{x^2}\implies dt/dx = 2/x^3\implies dt/2=dx/x^3$

$$\frac12\int\sqrt{t}\,{\rm d}t = \frac13t^{3/2}+C$$

Comment: how to connect  $1/x^3$ and  variable $t$ to each other?

Comment: @datodatuashvili when you subsitute $1-1/x^2=t$ you luckily get $\frac{dt}{2}=\frac{dx}{x^3}$.

Comment: So you don't have to connect $x^3$ separately, it gets clubbed with $dx$ and replaced with $dt/2$

Comment: aaa i see thanks in advance

Comment: i had not time to help one of  student,because i am at job now and :D

Answer (score 1):

When you introduce a new variable $y$, as you must know, you must differentiate the new variable in regard to the old (or, in other words, sloppily said: you must replace $dx$ with $dy$).

In your case, you have $$y=\frac{1}{x}$$ which means that $$dy = -\frac{1}{x^2} dx.$$ This means that $$\frac{1}{x^3}dx = -ydy.$$
Are the next steps any clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute 1/x*2 =t, ans will be 1/3(1-1/x*2)*3/2